# Graphic Libraries for BPMN?

Tags: graphics, graph, bpmn

We currently looking for software libraries for implementing a Web-based BPMN modeling tool in either Flex or DHTML (JavaScript, HTML 5, etc.). Free or non-free is okay.

Thanks.

Comment: We ultimately ended up using yFiles. The have implementations for Flex, Silverlight, and JavaScript. The team had a generally positive experience working with the Flex version and support from yFiles was very good.

Answer (score 2):

An Open Source web-based BPMN modeling tool already exists: [Oryx](http://bpt.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/Oryx)